# How do I incorporate the index in variable name when looping with each_with_index?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How would I incorporate the index in a variable name so that I could access the different group objects?

This is my db/seeds.rb file:

```
u = User.create( email: "yeah@foo.com", password: "yeah", password_confirmation: "yeah")

groups_list = ["Math Club", "Science Class", "Economics Class"]

groups_list.each_with_index do |name, index|
  "g#{index}" = u.groups.create(name: name)
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you start needing dynamically defined local variables you have a code smell and you know you should reconsider what you're doing.

It looks like you would be better served with a `map` call, converting the `groups_list` from an array of strings into an array of `Group` objects belonging to `u`:

```
groups_list.map { |name| u.groups.create name: name }
#=> [<Group name="Math Club">, …]
```

Then you can iterate through the groups or pass them into another method as an array, no trickery involved.

Comment: Thanks. Much better implementation. Just for the curious, could dynamically defined local variables be done?

Comment: No, Ruby doesn't support dynamically defining local variables. You can create instance ("`@foo`") and class variables ("`@@foo`") on the fly, but not local.

Comment: Well that's not entirely true, `/(?<bar>.*)/ =~ "42"` will create a local variable named `bar` with string value `"42"`. A `foo='baz'; /(?<#{foo}>.*)/ =~ "42"` does not work, though. I'd strongly advise **not** to do this in production code, if you ever want to understand that code again after your focus drifted away ;-)

Comment: @theTinMan: Well, then read the last paragraph of the official documentation on [Regex/Capture Groups](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html#label-Capturing): *»When named capture groups are used with a literal regexp on the left-hand side of an expression and the =~ operator, the captured text is also assigned to local variables with corresponding names.«* (The referred comment was deleted in the meantime...)

Comment: Defining a "local variable" based on a named pattern in a regex-match doesn't seem much different than using the indexed-patterns already available with regex matches. I'm not sure either could be used in any real way outside the method calling them, nor could they be used to add additional functionality. It's possible they could be used as an exploit I guess, if the exploiter had the source code.

Comment: As I sad, I'd advise not to use this feature (outside of [`MatchData`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/MatchData.html) objects, of course, named captures are so much more comfortable to work with than `$1` etc.). Anyway, I just mentioned the capture trick to contradict the "Ruby doesn't support dyn. def. variables", and I'm sure I could spawn another local variable either through `eval` or with [RubyVM::InstructionSequence](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/RubyVM/InstructionSequence.html) :-)

In any case, I have a feeling, I could not have gone more off topic :-))

Comment: I've known of the use of named parameters to create a local variable. I'm not sure I'd use it but it's there. I'd like to see the local-variable initialized via a regexp-match, used for what the OP asked for. While Ruby is internally generating a local variable, it's more like a red-herring in this context. Technically, you're correct, as a side-effect the local variable is generated. Creating it dynamically, and as a way to generate dynamically named variables and assigning values to them and looping... I think the answer is it's not doable in a reasonable way, especially for production use.